# Typing out all possible strings to use accessibilityRole?

Tags: typescript, react-native, accessibility

I'm using accessibilityRole in React Native. Do I have to type out all the possible strings, or is there an import that I can use?

```
createAccessibilityRole(parent: Element): string {
  if(isLink) return 'link'
  return 'text'
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, so I was wondering if we could import the type class or if we have to code it ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [official typing lib](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e3154f83485a8168f13831a89496b13a7cd804b5/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L2335)